# What fraction health care workers contract COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, infectious-diseases, healthcare-data

What fraction of health care workers contract COVID-19? Does anyone know of empirical evidence? Ideally, I’m looking for a reference to a study involving type of work, e.g., ER in close contact vs. receptionist greeting random sick people etc., and illness rates. Is it higher than in the general population?

Comment: possibly relevant, but only newspaper: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-netherlands-testin/dutch-test-blood-donations-for-unseen-coronavirus-spread-idUSKBN2161S4

Answer (score 1):

This is evolving. Originally there was a high percentage of medical staff (30%) being infected by sars-cov-2 in Wuhan but as the mode of transmission became clearer and ppe better, this has now improved so that no cases were reported outside of Hubei in China though it's being reported outside of China. Disease was also more severe in medical staff for unclear reasons and may relate to viral load exposure.

https://www.businessinsider.com/healthcare-workers-getting-coronavirus-500-infected-2020-2

Comment: I am (personally) interested mainly in health care systems similar to the US has. I know of these: https://arstechnica.com/staff/2020/03/us-healthcare-workers-already-hit-by-coronavirus-2-in-critical-condition/ , but would like to see numbers of non-critical cases, such as at BrighamWomans.

Comment: @DonSlowik Once China shifted to treating this virus in the same way Ebola is treated the infections in medical staff dropped to nil.  If you treat this virus any other way, you will see frontline staff infected.

Comment: Link to follow ?

Comment: The question asks about contracting the disease, while you respond regarding being infected by the virus. I think that it should be noted that those are quite different things.